# Python: Splitting a String and Keeping Characters Split On

Tags: python, regex, string

It's my first day working with regex, and I ran into a problem. The string i'm trying to manipulate is...

`1-11-1111A month and a day and a year.`

I'm trying to split into: `1-11-1111` and `A month a day and a year` using `splitstring = re.split(r'(?=\d+\d+\d+\d)', item)`, but the results are `1-11-` and `1111 A month a day and a year` and i'm not sure where i'm going wrong here based on what i've read. Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Try splitting on `r" (?<=\d)(?=A)`. That splits on the location (not character) between `1` and `A`. `(?<=\d)` is a *positive lookbehind*, meaning the match must be immediately preceded by a digit, but that digit is not part of the match. Similarly, `(?=A)` is a *positive lookahead*, meaning the match must be immediately followed by `A`, but that character is not part of the match.

Comment: If preferred, add a space after `A` in the positive lookahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options...

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'([0-9-]+)([A-Z].*)')

item = '1-11-1111A month and a day and a year.'

splitstring = [pattern.match(item)[1], pattern.match(item)[2]]
print(splitstring)
```

Output:

```
['1-11-1111', 'A month and a day and a year.']
```

Or using @Cary Swoveland's regex with the original split (works if it's a number followed by a capital 'A'...

```
splitstring = re.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=A)', item)
splitstring
```

Output:

```
['1-11-1111', 'A month and a day and a year.']
```